# Get value of json from api link

Tags: javascript, json, api

i have a api link from a game  "https://www.erevollution.com/en/api/citizen/1/"

and i want to get energy value

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <title>AutoHit for eRevollution</title>
    <style></style>
 </head>
  <body>

     <button id="button1" class="button button1" onclick="clicked()">Load Battle</button>           
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">

function clicked() { 
var url="https://www.erevollution.com/en/api/citizen/1";

const response = await fetch(url);
const myJson = await response.json();
console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
}

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Some notes, because it looks like you've used a really old tutorial to start on this: modern HTML needs a `<!doctype html>` at the top, and you don't use a `type` on the `<script>` element unless it's _not_ javascript. Also, don't use `alert`: it can only log simple strings, and blocks the JS thread. Get in the habit of using `console.log` instead, and looking at your dev tools console. Also on a modern JS note: everything you're doing can be done in standard JS these days. Use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), with automatic JSON parsing.

Comment: [Try this](https://jsfiddle.net/8hdqx3eg/)

Comment: Rather than just answering your question, I've written you an answer that shows how to do what you want to do with modern HTML and JS, and I would highly recommend you forget everything you learned and start afresh from a place that explains "HTML5" and refers to the version of JavaScript it uses as "ES6" or "ES2020" (or at least ES + some recent year). Skip tutorials that call what they teach you "ES5", which was superseded by newer versions of JS almost 5 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

There's a bunch of things that suggest you've been learning off of very old tutorials rather than modern HTML and JS tutorials (and not "a few years", the HTML/JS you're showing uses code and patterns we used back in 1998... the HTML/JS landscape has changed **drastically** since then).

So: let's fix some of this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- these two are not "nice to have", in modern browsers they're must-have boilerplate: -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- the title comes after the meta charset tag, because it's document text -->
    <title>AutoHit for eRevollution</title>
    <!-- let's also remember to style things properly -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <!-- note the link element has no "type" attribute, and does not need closing -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- If you need a button, use a button. Not an input element -->
    <button id="loadBattle" class="primary-btn" data-citizen="1">Load Battle</button>

    <!-- don't declare a type unless this is **not** javascript -->
    <script>
      // don't use "onclicked" in HTML or JS: use event listening.
      // Also, in modern HTML+JS, any element with an id can be directly
      // accessed on the JS-side by its id (provided you used a name
      // that is considered legal for JS variable naming purposes).
      loadBattle.addEventListener(`click`, event => {
          clicked(event, event.target.dataset.citizen);
      });

      // your API endpoint is a fixed value: make it a const
      const API_URL=`https://www.erevollution.com/en/api/citizen/`;

      function clicked(event, citizenNumber) {
        // compose the actual URL we need based on the base API url,
        // and the citizen number that we passed along
        let url = `${API_URL}${citizenNumber}`;

        // get the URL, using a standard API that uses the promise pattern.
        fetch(url)

        // if the URL fetch succeeds, the http response gets forward
        // to the next ".then()" in the chain, if there is one.
        // In this case, we use the built-in ".json()" function to turn
        // the response from a JSON string into a real JS object.
        .then(response => response.json())

        // then we take that real object, and we can do whatever we want.
        .then(data => {
            console.log(`data has ${data.length} entries`);
            console.log(`first entry:`, data[0]);
        })

        // And if things went horribly wrong: report that.
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This uses modern HTML code and conventions, and modern JS, including:

- ["const"ants rather than "var"iables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const),
- [event listening](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener),
- [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes),
- [string composition using template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals),
- [The Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch),
- [the promise pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises),
- [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), and
- the [Console API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console).

All of which became basic JS quite a few years ago, so it's worth "relearning" how to write for modern browsers.

Also note that `<script>` elements cannot (unfortunately; it would be useful if they could) load script code from *both* `src` and text content. So you can't do this:

```
<script src="jquery.js">
  $(...);
</script>
```

You *have* to use two script elements, and because most browsers (correctly) know that loading script "inline" (e.g. part of the page text) is easily changed, not just during a [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) "attack", but also by script that was allowed to run first, and thus has the ability to entirely rewrite your page, you really want to put your script in its own `.js` file that nothing can mess with.

Doing so also lets you mark your script as `defer`, meaning the browser will asynchronously load it in and only *execute* it [once the entire page source has been seen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>AutoHit for eRevollution</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <script src="index.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="loadBattle" class="primary-btn" data-citizen="1">Load Battle</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

With your JS in its own file:

```js
loadBattle.addEventListener(`click`, event => {
  clicked(event, event.target.dataset.citizen);
});

const API_URL=`https://www.erevollution.com/en/api/citizen/`;

function clicked(event, citizenNumber) {
  let url = `${API_URL}${citizenNumber}`;
  fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log(`data has ${data.length} entries`);
    console.log(`first entry:`, data[0]);
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```